# How to get dictionary value from reduceRegion in GEE Python

Tags: google-earth-engine, dictionary

The result printed in Python is empty dictionary.
How to get the value of regionReduce(mean)?

```
#%%
# Load input imagery: Landsat 7 5-year composite.
image = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LE7_TOA_5YEAR/2008_2012');

# Load an input region: Sierra Nevada.
region = ee.Feature(ee.FeatureCollection('EPA/Ecoregions/2013/L3')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('us_l3name', 'Sierra Nevada'))
  .first());

# Reduce the region. The region parameter is the Feature geometry.
meanDictionary = image.reduceRegion(
  reducer= ee.Reducer.mean(),
  geometry= region.geometry(),
  scale= 30,
  maxPixels= 1e9);

# The result is a Dictionary.  Print it.
print(meanDictionary);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You call `get()` on the dictionary to get a value from the dictionary. If you know the type of the value, you can also call `getArray()`, `getGeometry()`, `getNumber()`, or `getString()`. That would return the value with the corresponding type.

```
image = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LE7_TOA_5YEAR/2008_2012')
region = ee.Feature(ee.FeatureCollection('EPA/Ecoregions/2013/L3')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('us_l3name', 'Sierra Nevada'))
  .first()
)
meanDictionary = image.reduceRegion(
  reducer=ee.Reducer.mean(),
  geometry=region.geometry(),
  scale=30,
  maxPixels=1e9
)

print(meanDictionary.get('B1').getInfo())
```

Comment: thank you very much! it works!